# List Forms field ID issue-Assignment- in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: list-form, sharepoint-designer

I have created a `SPList` named Pets having 2 fields petname[`single line of text`] and pettype[`choice field`] and created a  new customform from this list using `SP Designer 2010`. Now I need to `presaveaction` and  some `jquery`,`spservices`  stuff in this form for validation and manipulation when save button is clicked.
But I am not seeing any ID of the field for applying the jQuery and  fetch the values.Am able to see the below code.

Can I create a separate ID/assign separate ID for each field in this form, just like we do in ASP.NET forms and visual web part using SP D?

```
       <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>PetName</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" 
              id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="PetName" 
             __designer:bind="
          {ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value',
         'ValueChanged','ID',
           ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@PetName')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" 
                 id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="PetName" 
             ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

currently this is my spd form looks like, ie the code for petname field.
am  confused by `id="ff2{$Pos}"`.

Can i use this in my jQuery/PreSaveAction 
validation as it is? If not, whats the best way of implementing this assignment of field IDs?

I have saved the form and form is appeared with these 2 fields. If I want to add 3rd column say a checkboxlist through SD P, how to achieve this?

I tried adding a new row and on the 2nd column I tried to `insert a control` abd added the `dvcheckboxlist`, but this action failed and my form becomes corrupted / shows error when clicked on `add new item`.

```
             <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>selections</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" 
               id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="selections" 
                     __designer:bind="
                {ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff4',$Pos),'Value',
              'ValueChanged','ID',
         ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@selections')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" 
                    id="ff4description{$Pos}" FieldName="selections" 
                   ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

here, I am having multiple checkboxes, but  in my `presaveaction`, how can I get the each & every ID of the checkboxes, such that, i can get the status of  each checkboxes when submit  button is clicked!

Below is my `F12 Dev tools` section of checkboxlist.Assuming that, i need to
port this code from one list to new list or new env.,i cant enter the same 
ids [ here ctl00_m_g_baff0aa2_5fdf_420b_ab45_b8235b35dcd3_ff4_1_ctl00_ctl00 ] 
to the new list as list ids would br diffeent for different lists.
So is there a way i can specify a ID like  id=chkboxforORCEBE" in my designer form such that, my `jQuery` validation is smooth.

ORCIBE

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to use JQuery, you can access the document elements on the client side using [title] attributes. Basically, you need to view source and analyze how to select the elements in JQuery. You can't use the ID as it's set by the server side code.

Here are few examples that might help:

```
$("input[title='myTextField']").val("");
$("select[title='MyChoiceField']").val("");
$('nobr:contains("DBType")').closest('tr').hide();
```

For JQuery selectors, visit [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)